# Unable to Build Notification FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm Receiving the notification but its built automatically by FireBase. I'm not able to set my own notification.I've tried to build the notification and set the title from onMessageReceived method but then it would stop displaying the notfication .Only the default notifications are shown

```
public class FireBaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("Msg", "Message received ["+remoteMessage+"]");

    // Create Notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebHandler.class);
    intent.putExtra("links","http://www.google.com");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Message")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
    }




}
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to send it?

Comment: When i receive the notification , I'm trying to build custom notification . For testing purpose i built a notification using the above code but only the default notification built by firebase is shown but not my custom notification